# How to obtain the probability that a gaussian variable is strictly positive?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, gaussian-integral, gaussian-measure

I am confused that which probability does the integral $\int_{0}^\infty \text{(pdf of gaussian) } dx$ equal to?

(1) the probability $P(X\geq 0)$

(2) $P(X>0)$

I believe it is equal to (1) , then my follow-up question is how to obtain the probability (2)?

This confused my a lot, since in my case, i would need to prove a variable is strictly positive, there is no chance for it to be zero.

Comment: They have the same probability.

Comment: @JoshuaTilley this confused my a lot, since in my case, i would need to prove a variable is strictly positive, there is no chance for it to be zero.

Comment: Is this question too trivial for everyone so there are many downvoted?

Comment: What does "no chance" mean in the context of this question? The other commenters tell you $P[X=0]=0$, which is the best that the theory of probability can tell you.  What is not clear to us whether you are asking if it is impossible for $X=0$ or if you are asking if $P[X=0]=0$, or even if you know the difference between the two statements.  That's probably the source of the downvotes: an unclear formulation of your question.

Comment: thanks for providing this. But 'it is impossible for $X=0$' is equivalent to '$P(X=0)=0$' right?

Comment: You can bet on $X\ne0$ but probability theory really does not actually rule $X=0$ out as being a logical impossibility.  That is, the event $[X=0]$ is a non-empty event that just happens to have probability $0$.  There are lots of other such events, including all events of form $[X=a]$ for each particular real number $a$.

Comment: @kimchilover Yes, $P(X=0)$ is really zero. But, could we rule out the event $X=0$? Lets say, although for each possible value of a continues random variable, the probability $X=a$ is zero, but the event $X=1$ still happens. For example, suppose $X$ to be the height of person, the event $X=1.7m$ still happens.

Comment: $P(X \ge 0) = P(X > 0)$ for any continuous distribution (such as the Gaussian distribution). Therefore, the integral in the question is equal to both ($1$) and ($2$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement that $X$ is a $N(0,1)$ random variable implies, among other things, that $P[X\ge0]=P[X>0] = 1/2$ and $P[X=0]=0$.

But, in the standard measure-theoretic formulation of what a [random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Measure-theoretic_definition) is, one cannot tell if the event  $[X=0]$ is the empty set, or just a set that happens to have probability $0$. One cannot conclude from $X\sim N(0,1)$ that $X=0$ is impossible, only that $P[X=0]=0$.

Suppose (in the notation of the cited Wikipedia page) that the underlying probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F, P)$ is $((0,1),\mathcal B(0,1), \lambda)$, where $\mathcal B(0,0)$ is the Borel sets in $(0,1)$ and $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure, and the random variable $X(\omega)=\Phi^{-1}(\omega)$, where $\Phi$ is cdf of the $N(0,1)$ distribution.   Now, define a new random variable $Y$ by the formula $$Y(\omega)=\begin{cases}X(\omega)&\omega\ne1/2\\17&\omega=1/2.\end{cases}$$

The random variables are (referring to the cited Wikipedia paragraph) equal in distribution (both  are $N(0,1)$-distributed), equal almost surely (because $P[X\ne Y]=0$), but not equal as functions on $\Omega$.  The event $[X=0]$ is  the set $\{1/2\}\subset \Omega$, which has Lebesgue measure $0$, but the event $[Y=0]$ is the empty set, which also has Lebesgue measure $0$.  The event $[X=17]$ is the set $\{\Phi(17)\}$ which has Lebesgue measure $0$, and the event $[Y=17]$ is the set $\{1/2,\Phi(17)\}$ whose Lebesgue measure is also $0$.